# Database 3rd Normal Form

Tags: database, forms, normalization, third-normal-form

Can somebody make sure my database is in the 3rd normal form, and if not, explain why not? 
I need the DB to only have 3 tables. So here it is:

```
Customer No. (PK)     Store No. (PK)     Sale No. (PK)
Name                  Location           Customer No. (FK)
Telephone             Revenue            Store No. (FK)
Address                                  Total
Purchases($)                             Paid
Store No.
```

Comment: It is not - the "Purchases" is going to be an ongoing list of incremental values that should have its own table (perhaps linked to the sale table?)

Comment: If i changed it to Total Purchases would the problem be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are what your three tables should be: Table 1: **Customer**

```
Customer No. (PK)
Name
Telephone
Address
```

then Table 2: **Store**

```
Store no. (PK)
Location
```

then Table 3: **Sale**

```
Sale No. (PK)
Customer No (FK)
Store No (FK)
Total
Paid_yes_no
```

If you are trying to track partial payments, etc. through the `Paid` column, then it would be a separate table (and a much more complicated database). However, if your `Paid` column just indicates whether the bill has been paid or not, the above should work.

Perhaps you need a `Date` field there as well?

Comment: Ok , ya i had intended the paid column to be a boolean data type. Thanks for your help!

Comment: While this makes logical sense, are the tables Customer and Sale fully normalized? For example Telephone does not depend on Name or Address, and neither of those fields are part of the primary key. Is this a violation of 4NF?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems, some of this may be as the specification is for homework rather than the real world.

- `Store No.` in Customers is a duplicated column  It's reasonable to expect that a business with multiple stores have customers who use multiple stores - unless your specification says otherwise and in which case the taxonomy (naming) should be expanded, you could consider *First Store No.* or *Home Store No.* instead.  Also it should be marked up as a foreign key if it is to remain.
- `Purchases($)` in the customers table is reliant on other data which will change.  Since it is derived from other information you should not store it.
- `Address` is not a single column - it has multiple parts like Street, City, State, Country & ZIP Code may in turn require extra tables details to fully satisfy 2nd Normal Form.  Similarly `Telephone` is unlikely to be just one number.

Each thing you need to know should appear once and once only.  If you can calculate it from something else you should do that rather than store the answer.  In the real world you might sometimes cache some information in a table or batch process it for performance, but those would be applied later and only if necessary.

A brief overview of database normalisation is at http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm which you should probably look through before reworking your project.